# access javascript object from json

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, synchronized

i want to load a local json-file and read the data with javascript/jquery. I bet it is a simple error from me but i can't get it to work. Here is the code, which i got so far:

**JSON-File:**

```
{
  "sound": {
    "title": "Bla 1",
    "file": "bla1"
  },
  "sound": {
    "title": "Bla 2",
    "file": "bla2"
  }
}
```

**JavaScript-Snippet**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'sounds.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: {},
    data: function(data) {audioFileLibrary = data},
    async: false
});
console.log("audioFileLibrary: " + audioFileLibrary);
console.log("currentAudioFile: " + audioFileLibrary[0]);
```

As output i got the following:

```
audioFileLibrary: [object Object]
currentAudioFile: undefined
```

For testing purposes i tried the following code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < audioFileLibrary.length; ++i){
    for(var ind in audioFileLibrary[i]) {
        console.log(ind);
        for(var vals in audioFileLibrary[i][ind]){
            console.log(vals, audioFileLibrary[i][ind][vals]);
        };
    };
};
```

But there is no output...
I hope somebody could show me way to solve the issue.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You switched `data` and `success`. :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

First fix the obvious errors in the code, by swapping the `data` and `success` properties in your AJAX call. That makes it work so far as getting you to your real problem:

Your JSON file contains an object that has two properties by the same name. When it is parsed, only one of them will remain in the result, as there can't be two properties in a Javascript object by the same name.

You can access that property using the name:

```
console.log("currentAudioFile: " + audioFileLibrary["sound"]);
```

If you want to be able to access both inner objects from the JSON, you need to change the JSON to have an array, for example:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Bla 1",
    "file": "bla1"
  },
  {
    "title": "Bla 2",
    "file": "bla2"
  }
]
```

Now you can access the first object using your original code.

Comment: I have changed the JSON file but it didn't change the result. But thanks for your answer and your help

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you'll probably want to use [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

```
$.getJSON( "sounds.json", function( json ) {
  console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.[0].title );
});
```

This assumes you correct your json file as recommended:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Bla 1",
    "file": "bla1"
  },
  {
    "title": "Bla 2",
    "file": "bla2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your code but i don't want to use the getJSON because i need synchronous call and the getJSON is asynchronous.

Comment: Completely missed the `async: false`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, according to [the docs for `$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), `data` is what you want to **send** to the server, not what is **returned**. You need to move the value of `data` to the `success` property instead.

Secondly, you are trying to access the property `0` of an object that in all likelihood has no such property. Your JSON is an object of objects: turn it into an array of objects and your `[0]` lookup should work.

Try this:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'sounds.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        audioFileLibrary = data;
        console.log("audioFileLibrary: " + audioFileLibrary);
        console.log("currentAudioFile: " + audioFileLibrary[0]);
    },
    async: false
});
```

With this data:

```js
[
  {
    "title": "Bla 1",
    "file": "bla1"
  },
  {
    "title": "Bla 2",
    "file": "bla2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Right you are - didn't see that bit. Thanks! I've edited to correct this =)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but i didn't get any output when i try your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON Object has two objects with the same key / name all you need to do is to give a unique key / name for each child object.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I had to change

```
audioFileLibrary = data;
```

into

```
audioFileLibrary = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data))
```

And now it works.